# Angular 10 routing after deploy on Azure not working (error 404)

Tags: angular, azure, hosting

I deploy my angular app on azure that works properly but **The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.** when i check my console it shows **404 not found**
what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You might need to configure the rewrite rules. If you're using Apache, this generator might be helpful: https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator

Comment: @HarunYilmaz i config but not work